# sp_setapprole in SQL server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to insert a value to a table in the database using a set of parameters, for which I want to make use of sp_setapprole. I know this sp can be used to set some permissions.

I am not aware how to even start.

My table: XYZ
Parameters: ViewerID, AppID, Key

I want to output Cookie and I want to query the table to delete/update and read a the parameter from another parameter.

Answer (score 0):

check with the below query

```
 DECLARE @cookie varbinary(8000);
EXEC sp_setapprole 'Sales11', 'fdsd896#gfdbfdkjgh700mM'
, @fCreateCookie = true, @cookie = @cookie OUTPUT;

-- The application role is now active.

SELECT USER_NAME();

-- This will return the name of the application role, Sales11.

EXEC sp_unsetapprole @cookie;

-- The application role is no longer active.
```

`-- The original context has now been restored`.

```
GO

SELECT USER_NAME();

-- This will return the name of the original user. 

GO
```

Comment: This is of quite help. Thankyou. But I am getting following errors: `Msg 15161, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_setapprole, Line 44
Cannot set application role 'optv_account' because it does not exist or the password is incorrect.`

**(1 row(s) affected)**

`Msg 290, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_unsetapprole, Line 22
Invalid EXECUTE statement using object "AppRole", method "Unset".`

Comment: just look your role in management studio and see the password is it proper as u entered

Comment: yes you need to configure role need to give permissions and define password. then try

Comment: I tried this `USE otv
EXEC sp_addapprole
  @rolename = 'Sales11',
  @password = 'pwd11'` It says **Msg 15023, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
User, group, or role 'Sales11' already exists in the current database.**